# Run function on search cross icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I run a javascript function when I click on the cross icon which appears when we type something in the search field.

```css
#search_input {
    width: 20rem;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
}

#search_input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    border-radius: 50em;
    background: url("https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/svgs/solid/times-circle.svg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    opacity: 0;
}

#search_input::-webkit-search-cancel-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#search_input:focus::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search_input" placeholder="Search" title="Cancel">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the cross icon reset the input, so I guess you can listen to event `input` and once this event is fired check:

- if the input is empty
- the event doesn't have a `inputType` property (this is a case when you type a key including delete)

Here is what the code would look like

```
const search = document.getElementById('search_input');

search.addEventListener('input', evt => {
    if(!evt.inputType && search.value === ''){
    console.log('search input has been cleared');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The cross icon is merely styling coming from the browser and is not selectable through JavaScript. You could however create your own version of a `<input type="search">` element by combining a `<input type="text">` and a `<button type="button"></button>` element.

Then you'll have control over what happens when clicking the cross icon. The example below mimics the behavior of the search element, but can be modified to do whatever you want when clicking the cross icon.

```js
const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-input');
const input = searchInput.querySelector('input');
const button = searchInput.querySelector('button');

input.addEventListener('input', event => {
  input.classList.toggle('has-value', event.target.value !== '');
});

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  input.classList.remove('has-value');
  input.value = '';
  console.log('cross clicked');
});
```

```css
.search-input {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.search-input > input,
.search-input > button {
  border: 0;
}

.search-input > button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.search-input > input.has-value + button {
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="search-input">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search"/>
  <button type="button">&times;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the script run when clicked on the input by adding an onclick attribute to `search_input` element.

```js
document.getElementById('search_input').onclick = function clickCancel() {
  console.log('clicked');
}
```

```css
#search_input {
  width: 20rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
}

#search_input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background: url("https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/svgs/solid/times-circle.svg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: 0;
}

#search_input::-webkit-search-cancel-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#search_input:focus::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  opacity: .3;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="search_input" placeholder="Search" title="Cancel">
```

Comment: it might be possible that the user wants to edit something for that he/she has to click on the text field and if we use onclick function than the event will fire but we don't want that we want the event to run when the cross button is clicked